# Convert Web Scraped JSON data to Pandas Dataframe / then CSV file

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I was able to web scrape some yahoo finance data with Python and JSON. I succeeded in printing these attributes in Jupyter Notebook. How do I make this a Pandas Dataframe, and then a CSV file?

```
import requests, re, json, pprint

p = re.compile(r'root\.App\.main = (.*);')
tickers = ['AAPL','ADBE', ...]
results = {}

with requests.Session() as s:

    for ticker in tickers:
        r = s.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}/key-statistics?p={}'.format(ticker,ticker))
        data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
        key_stats = data['context']['dispatcher']['stores']['QuoteSummaryStore']
        res = {
            'Current Price' : key_stats['financialData']['currentPrice']['raw'],
            'Trailing P/E' : key_stats['summaryDetail']['trailingPE']['raw']
        }
        results[ticker] = res

pprint.pprint(results)
```

I also couldn't seem to find the attribute "Long-Term Debt" or "Asset Turnover Ratio". That isn't my primary issue though. Please HELP

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Run as it is, your code raises `KeyError: 'QuoteSummaryStore'`

Comment: I'm very beginner level. How do I fix that?